# cast instructions as argument to container

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following conceptual problem:

```
template<class T> class foo {
    std::map<text, T *> bar;

    void push_back(T &t) { bar[(text) t] = t; }
}
```

This has surprisingly useful properties (if combined with other containers) but is not without limitations.

In particular, you cannot do this;

```
class tagged: public text;

foo<shared_ptr<tagged>> c;
```

As `foo` is not agnostic to its contents, and `shared_ptr` should not be the one cast.

We could do `bar[(text) *t] = t`, but that only moves the problem.

So instead I've been trying to come up with something more generic, where the caller defines how to cast. In pseudo:

```
template<class T, class Q = "text"> class foo {
    std::map<Q, T *> bar;

    void push_back(T &t) { bar[(Q) t] = t; }
}
```

Naturally above will not work. What would be an elegant solution?

Comment: You could add a functor that does the transformation for you on access

Comment: IMO this doesn't look like something you should do, even if you could. What is it actually that you are trying to achieve? It is already not that nice if you need to cast manually at all. A reinterpret or C-style cast is even more undesirable.
What is it that you aim for? Just putting shared_ptr of different types (but with a base type) in a container?

Comment: I basically have a vector where each element has both a name and an index, and can quickly access them as [x], where x is either one. See it as a sortable map with constant access time.

Comment: You might find [boost/multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/) useful for that. Or [boost/bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: If you want O(1) access time consider using std::unoredered_map from c++11. It has O(1) average compexity which may go up to O(N) if ablot of collisions are in the map.